# How to use TabbedPane onClick in blackberry 10 cascades?

Tags: blackberry-cascades

I have a problem while opening the layout2 from layout1.

Here is what i have tried..! It is not getting in to the layout2 from layout1.

```
                      `TabbedPane {
        showTabsOnActionBar: true 
                Tab {
                   Page {`

                          ImageButton {
                       id: loginbtn
                       onClicked: {


                            tabbedPaneSheet.open()
                       }

                       attachedObjects: Sheet {
                                   id: tabbedPaneSheet
                                   Editnew{
                                   }
                           }
```

and my Editnew Qml code

```
                        `TabbedPane {
                         id: mainTab
                   showTabsOnActionBar: true 
                        Tab {
                         title: "Home"
                              Group1 {
                                  id: homepage
                                   }
                                              }
                          Tab {
                            title: "Message
                              Messages {

    }
}

Tab {
    title: "Search"
            Search{
    }
}
Tab {
    title: "Feeds"

    Feeds {

    }
}

Tab {
    title: "Nearby"

    Nearby{
    }
}
Tab {
    title: "Followers"

    Followers {
        id: foll
    }
}
Tab {
    title: "Group"

    Groups {
        id: groups
    }
}`
```

The above code is not working and it is also throwing me no errors.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. 
It is because you open a tabbed pane from another tapped pane.

Try to make a simple page and with many segments and it will work with you.